# React: how to write if - else conditional statement in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a condition statement for the url that the user would click,
what i want to do is this, check if the `message.sender.id ===  user_id`, then i want to change the url to `${/inbox/}${message.reciever.id}${"/"}` and if the `message.sender.id !=== user_id`i need url to be `${/inbox/}${message.sender.id}${"/"}`

i don't know the best way to do this becuase the url is supposed to be in a map

```
{
  message.map((message) => (
    <Link className="chat-contacts-item" to={message.sender.id === user_id && `${/inbox/}${message.reciever.id}${"/"}`}>
     <p className="float-left">{message.message}</p>
    </Link>
  )
)}
```

```
<Link className="chat-contacts-item" to={message.sender.id === user_id &&`${/inbox/}${ message.reciever.id}${'/'}`}> 
    Click Now
</Link>
```

This is the one I wrote, how to write else statement here

```
{message.sender.id === user_id && 
  `${/inbox/}${ message.reciever.id}${'/'}`
}
```

Comment: `{message.sender.id === user_id  ?  ${/inbox/}${ message.reciever.id}${'/'} : ${/inbox/}${message.reciever.id}${'/'}}`   its missing the backtick because of the way comments are formatted but you just need to add them for the strings

Comment: You can use "ternary operator" ` condition === something? "true" : "not true"`

Comment: if use the `:` it returns syntax errors

Comment: @DestinyFranks You likely forgot to add backticks. stackoverflow turns them into code field. Make sure that your true and false statements are enveloped in backticks, just like in your example

Comment: Please look for [official docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Please [***search***](/search?q=jsx+if+else) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Link 
  className="chat-contacts-item" 
  to={"/inbox/" + (message.sender.id === user_id ? message.reciever.id : message.sender.id) + "/"}
>
    <p className="float-left">{message.message}</p>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the link before returning the UI, its better readable code.
Also, you can use same condition inside the `to={..}`

We call it ternary operator `something ? do this : else do this`

I hope this answer can help.

```
{message.map((message) => {
 const link = message.sender.id === user_id ? `${/inbox/}${message.reciever.id}${"/"}` : `${/inbox/}${message.sender.id}${"/"}`
    return (<Link className="chat-contacts-item" to={link}>
                <p className="float-left">{message.message}</p>
            </Link>
    )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way to do it in my opinion:

```
{
    message.map((message) => (
        <Link
            className='chat-contacts-item'
            to={`${/inbox/}${
                message.sender.id === user_id ? message.receiver.id : message.sender.id
            }${'/'}`}
        >
            <p className='float-left'>{message.message}</p>
        </Link>
    ));
}
```